# AJAX/Javascript retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm currently developing a chat application and I have stumbled across a problem on my javascript side.. The way my script retrieves its data based from the list of usernames listed on my html side from my database is working.. The problem is it loads correctly but after I try to click on another user it also loads the conversation overwriting the current conversation but it goes back to the 1st loaded conversation then loads the conversation again

The summary of my problem:
1st conversation overwrites 2nd conversation then reverts to the 1st conversation then goes back to 2nd conversation and goes on and on..

Here is my Javascript:

```
var load_target = $('#loads'),

loadThis = function (start_cycle) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadusers.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
      load_target
        .html(response);
        $('ul.chat-side-panel li').each(function (i) {
            var stats_li = $(this),
              bullet = stats_li.find('span.bullet'),
              mail = stats_li.find('span.mail'),
              typing = stats_li.find('span.typing-stats');

          bullet.toggleClass('online', (bullet.data('status') == 1))
          bullet.toggleClass('idle2', (bullet.data('status') == 2))
          mail.toggleClass('active', (mail.data('flag') == 1))
          typing.toggleClass('idle', (typing.data('type-status') == 0));



            stats_li.find("a").on("click", function(){
              $('.chatBox input[type="hidden"]').attr('value', $(this).data("userid"));
                  var  user= $(this).data("usernem");
                  var  uid = $(this).data("suid");
                  var rid = $(this).data("userid"),
                data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};
               id = setInterval(function(){
             $.ajax({
                  url: "includes/handlechat.php",
                  type: "GET",
                  data: data,
                  dataType: 'json',

               success: function(result){
              $("#clog").empty();
                $.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {

                 $("#clog").append('<p ><h4>'+ row.username +':</h4>' + row.message_content + '</p>' );

                });


              }

            })}, 1101);


            });        

        });
    },
    complete: function () {
      if (typeof start_cycle !== 'boolean' || start_cycle) {
        load_target.data('cycle_timer', setTimeout(loadThis, 2500));
      }
    }
  });
}

loadThis(false);
loadThis(true);
clearTimeout(load_target.data('cycle_timer'));



$(document).ready(function(){
  var dS1 = "flag=" + 2, dS0 = "flag=" + 1;
  $("#txtA").on("click, keyup", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'includes/type_notif.php',
      data: dS1,
      success: function (response) { }
    });
  });

  $(document).on("focusout", "#txtA", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'includes/type_notif.php',
      data: dS0,
      success: function (response) { }
    });
  });
});
```

Someone please help me on this I've been working on this module for week now.
Any tips and suggestion are very much appreciated. I'm quite desperate for help now =(

Answer (score 1):

Needing some code comments but maybe the problem is the setTimeOut, it is looping over and over again trough a array of users instead of loading only one. Maybe the content div is storing all the data without cleaning between users. Try this: Open Dev Console (in my case Chrome)

1. Elements, see the chat div and its content. Maybe multiple divs are being created.
2. Profiles: take a snapshot to see the summarize of detached elements. Profiles is the best way to view memory leaks. Take the snapshot, click on this new one and search Detached, see if the chat of user 1 is still there, maybe the cycling timer is looping trough detached elements.

Tips: clean up the chat div instead of append/html. I suggest using views (MVC).

Comment: hi sorry but what do you mean clean up instead of append/html?

Comment: Sometimes, like in Backbone MVC framework, the data stored in a div stands forever as a memory leak although you cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take into account web sockets? Your chat will work in push mode resolving all Your problems, improving user Experience and efficency. Take a look to the tomcat7 web app sample sincluded in the standard tomcat7 dist package. They provide a good chat implementati on based on  ajax and web sockets